# What is the alternative join query

Tags: mysql

Table: `items`

```
+---+-----------+
|id |    name   |
+---+-----------+
| 1 | Product-A |
| 2 | Product-B |
+---+-----------+
```

Table: `orders`

```
+---+-----+------------+
|id |price| orderer_id |
+---+-----+------------+
| 1 | 100 |      53    |
| 2 | 240 |      54    |
| 3 | 200 |      54    |
| 4 | 150 |      53    |
+---+-----+------------+
```

Table: `item_order`

```
+----+--------+---------+----------+
| id |order_id| item_id | quantity |
+----+--------+---------+----------+
| 1  |   1    |    1    |     2    |
| 2  |   1    |    2    |     3    |
| 3  |   2    |    2    |     2    |
| 4  |   3    |    1    |     1    |
| 5  |   3    |    2    |     1    |
| 6  |   4    |    1    |     2    |
| 7  |   4    |    2    |     2    |
+----+--------+---------+----------+
```

What to extract:

For each `orderer_id`, `number_of_order`, `total_quantity`, `total_price`

```
+---------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+
| orderer | number_of_order | total_quantity | total_price |
+---------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+
|   53    |        2        |        9       |     250     |
|   54    |        2        |        4       |     440     |
+---------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Current approach:
    *Using correlated sub-query*

```
select orderer_id as orderer, 
    count(*) as number_of_order, 
    sum(select quantity from item_order where item_order.order_id = orders.id) as total_quantity, 
    sum(price) as total_price
from orders
order by orderer_id
```

**Can it be solved by joining `item_order` with `orders` ? If yes, how?**

Another approach I thought -

1. `select ... from orders`
2. `select ... from item_order`
3. combine and format as required in `application layer`

**As you can assume, `orders` and `item_order` table will grow much larger, which solution will be better?**

Comment: It seems an odd design where item_order does not know the unit price and items does not know the item price.

Comment: So we can't use inner join right ?

Comment: It is not the complete table structure. There are a few columns with each of the tables. Here I added only those(at minimum), which will help to get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the one-to-many relation from `orders` to `item_order` it is easier to perform aggregation in a subquery and `JOIN` to the derived table:

```
SELECT o.orderer_id,
       COUNT(o.id) AS number_of_order,
       SUM(io.quantity) AS total_quantity,
       SUM(o.price) AS total_price
FROM orders o
JOIN (SELECT order_id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
      FROM item_order
      GROUP BY order_id) io ON io.order_id = o.id
GROUP BY o.orderer_id
```

Output:

```
orderer_id  number_of_order total_quantity  total_price
53          2               9               250
54          2               4               440
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qeJwgip8UTcz5EeBhsJfDf/0)

I would expect this to be faster than the correlated subquery as that query has to be performed for every row in the `orders` table whereas the query for the derived table, although more complicated, is executed only once. I would also expect this to be faster than the option of performing two queries and combining in the application layer.

Comment: What if the table size increase?

Comment: @MASh I would expect this to get even faster than the alternatives. But ultimately it is always best to benchmark on your actual data. You can just compare the two queries, I would be very surprised if performing the work in the application layer was faster.

Comment: @MASh It's not just size. It's also 'density'. A 'sparse' dataset may perform differently to a 'dense' one.

Comment: Until now, this is the best answer to me. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this please

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `price` INTEGER,
  `orderer_id` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO orders
  (`id`, `price`, `orderer_id`)
VALUES
  ('1', '100', '53'),
  ('2', '240', '54'),
  ('3', '200', '54'),
  ('4', '150', '53');

CREATE TABLE item_order (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `order_id` INTEGER,
  `item_id` INTEGER,
  `quantity` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO item_order
  (`id`, `order_id`, `item_id`, `quantity`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '1', '2'),
  ('2', '1', '2', '3'),
  ('3', '2', '2', '2'),
  ('4', '3', '1', '1'),
  ('5', '3', '2', '1'),
  ('6', '4', '1', '2'),
  ('7', '4', '2', '2');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
with cte0 as 
(
select 
  orderer_id orderer,
  count(distinct o.id) number_of_order,
  sum(io.quantity) total_quantity
from orders o
inner join item_order io
  on io.order_id = o.id
group by orderer_id
), cte1 as 
( 
select 
  orderer_id, 
  sum(price) total_price
from orders
group by orderer_id
)
select orderer, number_of_order, total_quantity, total_price from cte0
inner join cte1 
  on cte0.orderer = cte1.orderer_id;
```

---

```
| orderer | number_of_order | total_quantity | total_price |
| ------- | --------------- | -------------- | ----------- |
| 53      | 2               | 9              | 250         |
| 54      | 2               | 4              | 440         |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)